# How to handle the multitenancy problem in Spring Boot applications?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, multi-tenant

Let's imagine I have a `SpringBoot` app with the following requirements.

1. It has a `User` class (entity)
2. Each user has zero or more `Workspaces` (one-to-many entity relationship)
3. Each `Workspace` has zero or more `WorkItems` (one-to-many entity relationship)

There is a CRUD REST API controller to manage all of the entities, i.e. we have

1. `UserController` -> CRUD operations for `User` entity
2. `WorkspaceController` -> CRUD operations for `Workspace` entity
3. `WorkItemContoller` -> CRUD operations for `WorkItem` entity

Now there are requirements that ...

1. A `User` can only create/edit/delete his own `Workspace` entities
2. A `User` can only create/edit/delete `WorkItem` entities in his own `Workspaces`

Also, assume that the `User` entity is integrated with `SpringSecurity` and we know the current user in the contoller and service.

**Then the question is ...**

What is the most elegant/clean/maintainable way to implement user permission checks ? How do we write the code, which in the `Service` classes will check that the user is authorized to perform operations on a given resource.

The way I do it now is that there's a class like this, which checks the permissions in every `Service` call.

```
class PermissionManager {
   void checkUserAllowedToUseWorkspace(User u, Workspace w);
   void checkUserAlloweToUseWorkitem(User u, WorkItem)
}
```

As you can see ... as the number of scoped resources will grow ... this class will get super bloated and hard to maintain.

Is anyone aware of a better way to do this **scoped** resource access in a clean and maintainable way ?

Comment: Assuming JPA and with that Hibernate, use hibernate filters to limit the results of queries based on the user itself. You can use AOP to enable the filter to have automatic filtering applied. Then a user only sees (and thus can modify) its own data.

Comment: Hi, @M.Deinum. Sounds like a cool approach to limit the repository output based on associated user entity. Can you, maybe, send me the link to an article which shows how to do it with a code example ?

Comment: https://callistaenterprise.se/blogg/teknik/2020/10/17/multi-tenancy-with-spring-boot-part5/ which shows the filter approach. Instead of the tenant used just write a query which includes your userid (and you can use the `SecurityContextHolder` to obtain the current user.

Comment: Why don't you add user id to each database query which is not related that user, can not perform operation and you can throw exception.

Comment: Also you can get user from SecurityContextHolder which you need to put when authenticate user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most clean and maintainable solution would be to leverage *Spring Security* AOP for the task.

You can use the `@PreAuthorize` annotation, paired with your `PermissionManager` service to allow or reject access at the `Controller` level harnessing the power of *Spring Expression Language*.

Having defined a `Service` stereotype that checks the user access to a particular resource (the workspace in your example):

```
@Service
public class PermissionManagerImpl implements PermissionManager {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

   /**
   * @param authentication the current authenticated user following your authentication scheme
   * @param workspaceId the workspace (or other resource) identifier
   */
    @Override
    public boolean checkUserAllowedToUseWorkspace(Authentication authentication, Long workspaceId) {
        return authentication != null
                /* check that the `authentication` has access to the argument workspace: e.g. userRepository.findWorkspaceByUserNameAndWorkspaceId(authentication.getName(), workspaceId) != null */;
    }

}
```

You can define an expression based control policy on your `Controller` method as follows:

```
@RestController
public class WorkspaceController {

    // the DIed `permissionManagerImpl` service will be called prior to your endpoint invocation with the current `authentication` and workspace `id` injected
    @PreAuthorize("@permissionManagerImpl.checkUserAllowedToUseWorkspace(authentication, #id)")
    @RequestMapping("/workspaces/{id}")
    public List<Workspace> getWorkspaces(@PathVariable Long id) {
        // retrieve the user workspaces once authorized
    }
}
```

This will lead a readable and reusable solution acting on the top level resource, the `Controller`.

You can learn more on [*Expression-based Access Control* in the official *Spring* docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/servlet/authorization/expression-based.html).

Comment: @PreAuthorize("@permissionManagerImpl. checkUserAllowedToUseWorkspace(authentication, #id)")

So in this line Spring will automatically inject the authentication object ?

Comment: Yes, given you have your security configuration set properly.

Answer (score 0):

Some database queries for Workspace Entity :

```
// DELETE
@Transactional
void deleteByIdAndUserId(String workspaceId, String userId);

userRepository.deleteByIdAndUserId(workspaceId, userId);


// UPDATE
Optional<Workspace> workspace = workspace.findByIdAndUserId(String workspaceId, String userId);

Workspace workspace = workspace.orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("You don't have an workspace under user "))

workspace.setName("MyWorkspace2");

//CREATE
User user = userRepository.findById(SecurityContextHolder...getPriciple().getId())
              .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("User can not be found by given id"));
workspaceRepository.save(WorkspaceBuilder.builder().user(user).name("firstWorkspace").build());
```

Comment: And then I do all the checks in the repository code ?